# Error with the CMakeLists.txt in opencv project

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

I'm begining an opencv project in C++ and I figure that it'll be a nice occasion to learn some cmake. This is my project hirerachy:

```
project/
|__include/
   |__sample1.h
   |__sample2.h
|__build/
|__doc/
|__src/
   |__sample1.cpp
   |__sample2.cpp
|__test/
   |__main.cpp
|__CMakeLists.txt
```

The CMakeLists.txt is :

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED( VERSION 2.8 )

SET( PROJ_NAME      "Project" )
SET( PROJ_PATH      ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} )
SET( PROJ_OUT_PATH  ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} )
SET( PROJ_LIBRARIES ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
SET( PROJ_INCLUDES  "include" )

FILE( GLOB_RECURSE PROJ_SOURCES src/*cpp test/*cpp )
FILE( GLOB_RECURSE PROJ_HEADERS include/${PROJ_NAME}/*.h )

PROJECT( ${PROJ_NAME} )
FIND_PACKAGE( OpenCV REQUIRED )
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES( ${PROJ_INCLUDES} )
ADD_EXECUTABLE( ${PROJ_NAME} ${PROJ_SOURCES} )
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES( ${PROJ_NAME} ${PROJ_LIBRARIES} )
```

The makefile is generated, but when I execute "make" I have some "undefined references" to opencv functions.

Any help would be appreciated, and of course if you want more information just ask :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SET( PROJ_LIBRARIES ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

OpenCV_LIBS will be set AFTER you search for the package with find_package().

You also need to add your headers to add_executable().